# Cosmosdb migration using dt.exe command line

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, dt

I've an azure cosmosdb database which I want to migrate to different cosmosdb environments. Firstly, I want to migrate the database from azure platform into my local azure emulator. I've tried the following command

```
dt.exe /s:DocumentDB /s.ConnectionString:"AccountEndpoint=https://portfolio.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=EAXW4PkLzoWsDLMVSOsKh3o5sbMiI4ggIlBLbsQ8hM1B07yHxMFbsqHDAv1AmCqisRrdwJsPgJqsYXBMWx4VNUA==;Database=DailyPortfolio;" /s.Collection:Schemes /t:DocumentDBBulk /t.ConnectionString:"AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==;Database=DailyPortfolio;" /t.Collection:Schemes /t.PartitionKey:/SchemeId /t.CollectionThroughput:2500
```

I am getting the following error,

```
Failures:
5801E67E-3A37-44A0-9073-09F98F63CD40: PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.
```

But I've supplied the `/t.PartitionKey:/SchemeId` and also I've tried as follows `/t.PartitionKey:"/SchemeId"` but still I get the same error.

It works perfectly fine with the graphical tool dtui.exe

Any ideas?

Comment: can you try removing the leading slash in the partition key property name?

Comment: I've tried, it returned the same error

Comment: I have removed the /t.CollectionThroughput:2500 and worked!

Comment: @GarryA You can post an answer to end this question.

Comment: Here you go, dt.exe /s:DocumentDB /s.ConnectionString:"AccountEndpoint=https://portfolio.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=EAXW4PkLzoWsDLMVSOsKh3o5sbMiI4ggIlBLbsQ8hM1B07yHxMFbsqHDAv1AmCqisRrdwJsPgJqsYXBMWx4VNUA==;Database=DailyPortfolio;" /s.Collection:Schemes /t:DocumentDBBulk /t.ConnectionString:"AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==;Database=DailyPortfolio;" /t.Collection:Schemes /t.PartitionKey:/SchemeId

Comment: @GarryA I help you post an answer. This can be benefit to others.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the  /t.CollectionThroughput:2500 and worked.

```
dt.exe /s:DocumentDB /s.ConnectionString:"AccountEndpoint=https://portfolio.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=EAXW4PkLzoWsDLMVSOsKh3o5sbMiI4ggIlBLbsQ8hM1B07yHxMFbsqHDAv1AmCqisRrdwJsPgJqsYXBMWx4VNUA==;Database=DailyPortfolio;" /s.Collection:Schemes /t:DocumentDBBulk /t.ConnectionString:"AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==;Database=DailyPortfolio;" /t.Collection:Schemes /t.PartitionKey:/SchemeId
```

Answer (score 0):

Bulk import mode is only for single partition Collections (no partition key). When importing data into a Collection that has a partition key defined, sequential record import mode must be used. So instead of `/t:DocumentDBBulk`, use:

```
/t:DocumentDB
```

I don't know why the bulk import mode contains the /t.PartitionKey option, it doesn't seem to work.

In the graphical tool `dtui.exe`, the sequential mode is chosen by default so it's easy to miss that option in the command-line tool.